# find indices where df value is in bin range of other df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column df2["v2"] in a dataframe filled with the values from a different dataframe df1["v1"].

The first dataframe holds values from measurement 1 which are measured at the times stored in df1["T1"]. The second dataframe should now store the values from measurement 1, but has a different time sampeling. In the real world task the time sampling is not evenly spaced (nor monotonically increasing, at least by default).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"T1": [0, 5, 10, 15], "v1":[0, 1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"T2": np.arange(0, 15)})
```

A stupid way of doing this could be:

```
df2["v2"] = pd.Series()
for n in range(df1["T1"].size-1):
   t1 = df1["T1"].iloc[n]
   t2 = df1["T1"].iloc[n+1]
   mask =  (t1 <= df2["T2"]) & (df2["T2"] < t2)
   df2["v2"].loc[mask]= df1["v1"].iloc[n]
```

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
    T2   v2
0    0  0.0
1    1  0.0
2    2  0.0
3    3  0.0
4    4  0.0
5    5  1.0
6    6  1.0
7    7  1.0
8    8  1.0
9    9  1.0
10  10  2.0
11  11  2.0
12  12  2.0
13  13  2.0
14  14  2.0
```

Whats the fastest/most elegant way of achieving the same?

Comment: Please post expected output also.

Comment: Also, in the code you posted you refer to ```df```, while the 2 dataframes you create are called ```df1``` and ```df2``` respectively.

Comment: thanks, corrected typos and added output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of solving the problem with **[`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)**:

```
bins = pd.cut(df1['T1'], df1['T1'], right=False)
mapping = df1[:-1].set_index(bins[:-1])['v1']

df2['v2'] = df2['T2'].map(mapping)
```

**Details:**

Categorize the values in column `T1` into **discrete intervals** characterised by the column `T1` itself:

```
>>> bins

0      [0.0, 5.0)
1     [5.0, 10.0)
2    [10.0, 15.0)
3             NaN
Name: T1, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[int64]): [[0, 5) < [5, 10) < [10, 15)]
```

Create a `mapping` series:

```
>>> mapping

T1
[0, 5)      0
[5, 10)     1
[10, 15)    2
Name: v1, dtype: int64
```

`map` the values in the column `T2` with help of above `mapping` series:

```
>>> df2

    T2  v2
0    0   0
1    1   0
2    2   0
3    3   0
4    4   0
5    5   1
6    6   1
7    7   1
8    8   1
9    9   1
10  10   2
11  11   2
12  12   2
13  13   2
14  14   2
```